# How do I get the data from my Google fusiontable via a browser get-request?

Tags: google-api, google-fusion-tables

I don't know what else I could do to get the data via a browser get-request from my google fusiontable.

The fusiontable is public and downloadable and the Google Fusion Tables App is authorized.
When I call this:

> https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?sql=SELECT * FROM
>   MY_FUSIONTABLE_ID&key=MY_KEY

I get this response:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "accessNotConfigured",
    "message": "Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project."
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project."
 }
}
```

Why does this happen?
I created a Project in the Google Developer Console and created a Server Key and a Browser Key each - they are both not working. Which one do I have to use? 
I already acticated all!  Apis for my project, since I thougth, I didn't activate the right one. Still not working.

When I read "usageLimits" I thought, maybe my table has too many rows. But neither LIMIT 10 in the Query works nor delete all rows but 3 in the fusiontable.

Any ideas, why it still says "accessNotConfigured"?
Is there a way to connect my fusiontable to my project in the developer console?

Thanks for every hint!
Greetings,
Jan

Comment: What is the FusionTable? Is it public and do you have 'download' allowed (you say you do, but that is where I usually see this particular error)?  Do you have the "Fusion Tables API" ON in the API Console? What are the referers for the browser key?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "What is the FusionTable"?
THe table is definitely public and "Allow downloads" is checked.
"Fusion Tables API" is set to "on" in the project I created with the google developer console.
There are 2 referers: one is my domain, which I'll use in the future and the other one is "*.googleapis.com/*".

Comment: By "what is the FusionTable", I mean what is the table ID (or provide a link to the table), or that of an example table with the same format and test data that exhibits the issue.  The .googleapis.com referer is probably useless, unless your page is on that domain.  You certainly need to include the referer for whatever domain you are testing from, as a test generate a key that works for all referers.

Comment: 1-GccVjOLNKXkW7gyVNEFZhkOz3E-fmjfXT_w77M is the ID.
I've added * to the referer list, but it's still not working.

Comment: https://www.google.com/fusiontables/data?docid=1-GccVjOLNKXkW7gyVNEFZhkOz3E-fmjfXT_w77M#rows:id=1  is the link

Comment: Everything looks OK to me.  Can you create a fiddle that exhibits the problem (or provide a link to a page that does)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This message is only related to the project, not to the particular table(I'm able to request your table with my key).

As the message says, the Fusion Tables API -service is not activated for this project.

So check(again):

1. If the used key is the key generated for this project(you may have multiple projects)
2. If the Fusion Tables API -service is activated for this particular project

Comment: Thanks Dr.Molle for the hint regarding the multiple project.
I was using the wrong project or rather the one with restrictions regarding the referer for the browser-key.
Strange, since I created my first project for this fusiontable.
Must have overseen something.
Now its working!